# add sum of the rows in each column in data grid bind to datasource

Tags: c#

i have dynamic columns in datagrid which bind to datasource.Now i want to add sum of the each column as a last row to the each column my code is

```
DataTable dt = dgvReport.DataSource as DataTable;
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.Add(row);
row[0] = "Totals";
for (int i = 1; i < dgvReport.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < dgvReport.Rows.Count; ++j)
    {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(dgvReport.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

but it is not working.I need for each column
   15
   10

### 30

55

Comment: What is the error ? Is not working is not very useful ...

Comment: At last row of each column or at last column of each row?

Comment: I think you want additional column right then syntax dt.Columns.Add(newColumn)

Comment: And more guessing coming for "what OP want to achieve" :)

Comment: sum of the all rows in each column in last row of that column

Comment: What is the output? Can You add some screenshot/dataGrid  output?

Comment: Can you add your table schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're summing all rows, including "Total" row that has no value. And don't need to use ToString() and then cast as integer.

According to your loop, I assume Colum[0] and Row[0] has the captions of your table.

```
|------|-------|------|------|
|      | Cap1  | Cap2 | Cap3 |
|------|-------|------|------|
| Cap1 |  10   |  20  |  10  |
|------|-------|------|------|
| Cap2 |  15   |  10  |  13  |
|------|-------|------|------|
|Totals|  25   |  30  |  23  |
|------|-------|------|------|

DataTable dt = dgvReport.DataSource as DataTable;
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.Add(row);
row[0] = "Totals";

for (int i = 1; i < dgvReport.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = ; j < dgvReport.Rows.Count; ++j)
    {
        if ( j < dgvReport.Rows.Count - 1)
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(dgvReport.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value);
        else
            dgvReport.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value = sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your actual problem, but converting from `string` to a `int` should be done using `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse`.

```
sum += int.Parse(dgvReport.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value.ToString());
```

However, in your case I guess you already have integers in the cells, in which case you only need the `Convert.ToInt32`, without calling `ToString` before.

```
sum += Convert.ToInt32(dgvReport.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value);
```

Comment: Value of the Cell is already an integer, so you need only to cast it: `(int)dgvReport.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value`